# System.Xml.XmlException: "Отсутствует метка порядка байт в Юникоде. Переход в Юникод невозможен."

Tags: c#, xml

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (File.Exists("D:\\Data.xml"))
        {


        }

        else
        {
            var balance = new Balance
            {
                Money = 0,
                LastIncome = 0,
                LastLoss = 0,
                Income = 0,
                Loss = 0,
            };

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Balance));
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, balance);
            string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText("D:\\Data.xml", xml);

        }
        Balance b = new Balance();

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xDoc.Load("D:\\Data.xml");
    }
```

Comment: Какая строка исходного кода не работает?

Answer (score 0):

XML был сериализован как utf-16 в файловой системе:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Это создало конфликт между прологом XML (utf-16) и фактической кодировкой тела файла XML (utf-8). Вот почему загрузка XML-документа не удалась в этой строке:

```
xDoc.Load("D:\\Data.xml");
```

Решение было простым. Используйте LINQ to XML и рассматривайте XML как тип данных XML.
Я закомментировал не нужные строки.
Конечный результат XML сериализуется следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

и все работает.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\Data.xml";

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        var balance = new Balance
        {
            Money = 0,
            LastIncome = 0,
            LastLoss = 0,
            Income = 0,
            Loss = 0,
        };

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Balance));
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, balance);
        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(stringWriter.ToString());

//      File.WriteAllText(fileName, xml);
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null), xml);

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "\t";
        settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
    }

//  Balance b = new Balance();
//  XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
//  xDoc.Load("D:\\Data.xml");
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
}

public class Balance
{
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public int LastIncome { get; set; }
    public int LastLoss { get; set; }
    public int Income { get; set; }
    public int Loss { get; set; }
}
```

> Output file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Balance xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Money>0</Money>
   <LastIncome>0</LastIncome>
   <LastLoss>0</LastLoss>
   <Income>0</Income>
   <Loss>0</Loss>
</Balance>
```